# Seeking Clarification: Necropolitan Template

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-templates

I'm planning to start building my human character from level 1 with the intention of becoming "necropolitan" and "evolved undead". Naturally, given the requirements of the "necropolitan" template, I must be at least level 2 and have at least 1000 extra XP to avoid perishing in the attempt.

However, I'm struggling to grasp exactly how the loss of levels and XP would function mechanically.

Here are my two interpretations, based on my lack of familiarity with the system, using the example of my character having 4000 XP:

1. Would I lose 2000 XP (which is the amount needed to go from level 2 to 3) plus an additional 1000 XP? This would leave me with a total of 1000 XP, which should be sufficient to be at level 2.
2. Would I lose all of my accumulated XP, resulting in a reset to level 2, leaving me with 1000 XP? Then, subsequently losing 1000 XP would leave me at level 1 (with 0 XP).

I would greatly appreciate any clarification you can provide on this matter. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an annoying goose chase of tracking down a chain of references to rules elsewhere, but here it is:

> Immediately upon opening its undead eyes, a new necropolitan loses a level as if the spell raise dead had been used on it and it was alive instead of animate. (If the subject has no levels to lose, it is simply destroyed.) It then also loses an additional 1,000 XP. If the loss of this much XP forces the necropolitan to lose another level, then it loses another level. […] Petitioners
> may not spend experience points they don’t have—if the level
> loss and the 1,000 XP cost drains a creature to 0 XP or less, it
> is destroyed, turned to dust, and can never be raised or revived
> again using any means.

<sup>(*Libris Mortis*, Creating a Necropolitan, Ritual of Crucimigration, pg. 115)</sup>

So to survive the Ritual of Crucimigration, one must have enough XP to lose a level, as with *raise dead*, and still have at least 1,001 XP remaining.

So how much XP do you have left after *raise dead*?

> Coming back from the dead is an ordeal. The subject of the spell loses one level (or 1 Hit Die) when it is raised, just as if it had lost a level or a Hit Die to an energy-draining creature.

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook*, *raise dead* spell description, pg. 268)</sup>

The same amount of XP you’d have after a negative level becomes permanent…

> Negative levels remain for 24 hours or until removed with a spell, such as *restoration*. After 24 hours, the afflicted creature must attempt a Fortitude save […] If the save fails, the negative level goes away, but the creature’s level is also reduced by one (see Level Loss, page 296).

<sup>(*Dungeon Master’s Guide*, Energy Drain and Negative Levels, pg.293)</sup>

…which is apparently described at yet another location…

> A character who loses a level instantly loses one Hit Die. […] The victim’s experience point total is immediately set to the midpoint of the previous level. For example, a character drained from 2nd to 1st level would drop to 500 experience points.

<sup>(*Dungeon Master’s Guide*, Level Loss, pg. 296)</sup>

…and now we finally have actual rules, halfway between our previous level and the level we lost. Note that this doesn’t care how much XP you had towards the *next* level: if you lose 5th level, you go to 8,000 XP (halfway between 4th and 5th), regardless of whether you had exactly 10,000 XP (the minimum for 5th) or 14,999 XP (the maximum for 5th, since 6th requires 15,000 XP).

Anyway, we still have to consult the table of how much XP is required for each level:

> ##### Table 3–2: Experience and Level-Dependent Benefits
>
> | Character Level | XP | […] |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1st | 0 | […] |
> | 2nd | 1,000 | […] |
> | 3rd | 3,000 | […] |
> | 4th | 6,000 | […] |
> | 5th | 10,000 | […] |
> | 6th | 15,000 | […] |
> | 7th | 21,000 | […] |
> | 8th | 28,000 | […] |
> | 9th | 36,000 | […] |
> | 10th | 45,000 | […] |
> | 11th | 55,000 | […] |
> | 12th | 66,000 | […] |
> | 13th | 78,000 | […] |
> | 14th | 91,000 | […] |
> | 15th | 105,000 | […] |
> | 16th | 120,000 | […] |
> | 17th | 136,000 | […] |
> | 18th | 153,000 | […] |
> | 19th | 171,000 | […] |
> | 20th | 190,000 | […] |

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook*, Level-Dependent Benefits, pg. 22)</sup>

So if you undergo the Ritual of Crucimigration while 2nd level, you drop to 1st level and 500 XP, and then lose 1,000 XP, bringing you to −500 XP and death. It doesn’t matter if you have 1,000 XP or 2,999 XP; you will die the same. To survive, you need to be 3rd level: then you drop to 2nd level and 2,000 XP, and then lose 1,000 XP to go to 1,000 XP, which is enough to still be 2nd level. Again, it doesn’t matter if you have 3,000 XP or 5,999 XP, the result is the same, so ideally you’d perform the Ritual as soon as you level up to 3rd.

Comment: This answer makes me anxious. The SRD deliberately omits the XP chart so that players would have to buy the *Player's Handbook*. Fifteen years ago, this answer probably would've gotten a C&D; I don't know if the same'll happen now, but I'd rather the answer be safe than sorry and quote the minimum.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don’t think it would have. The SRD omits the XP table, and this it is not open-game content, but that only matters to those who are licensing the content under the OGL. We are not; this is being quoted under a fair use rationale, not under any license. I can’t know for sure that Wizards would not have sent a C&D over this, but I am dubious. At any rate, that’s their business to figure out, not really ours. Without the complete list of XP requirements, I cannot back up the claim that 3,000 XP is optimal.

Comment: It may be worth noting that Necropolitan has some unusual interactions with LA. I would definitely understand if you don't care enough to go into it though.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I'm confused, is [this page](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/xp.htm) not part of the SRD?

Comment: @Carmeister I can't quickly find the actual SRD, but I'm fairly confident that info is not part of it. The "SRD" is an actual document published by WOTC and licensed for others' reuse. The D20SRD website is a derivative work not published by WOTC. I think it's strongly related that nothing links to the xp page, so it won't be indexed by search engines.

Comment: @KRyan: I think you could safely truncate the table to only have the first 3 levels. The other levels are unrelated to your answer.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I could work around such a limitation, yes. I don’t think the answer would be everything it could or should be. And I don’t see any reason to do so.

Comment: My knowledge of fair use stems from the education field, so grain of salt when I say that I understand fair use to mean that you don't reproduce enough of the product to impact sales of the product. My understanding is also that the XP table was in the *PH* then omitted from the SRD and not allowed to be printed elsewhere *deliberately* so folks would have to buy the *PH*. Because of that, the answer to me looks like an excuse to print the XP table. I don't *care*, of course, as WOTC has treated *3.5* fans badly for the last fifteen years, too, so, "Meh," I guess?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I’ll admit, I don’t know how fair use considers the “context” like that, but _this work alone_ is not sufficient to play 3.5e without buying the books. Even this whole site isn’t (remotely) that. This site plus the SRD pretty much gets you there, but... is that our responsibility? We didn’t put the SRD out there. Anyway, in the end, stuff like “impact on sales of the product” is one of many things that the law directs judges and/or juries to consider in cases of fair use, neither damning nor exonerating on its own. I think WotC would have a hard time here.

Comment: @KRyan RE: "[T]his work alone is not sufficient to play 3.5e without buying the books." I did not say that it was. To be clear, what I meant was that a player *needs* the XP table, and that it's unavailable elsewhere. It shouldn't be in Arthaus's Ravenloft material, Atlas's Oriental Adventures material, or any other product, and if you wanted to play *those other games* then, even if you didn't need the rest of the *PH*, you'd need to buy the *PH* *only* for the XP table. *That's* the revenue stream. Unless the player consults this answer, of course. `:-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan Or just makes up their own numbers, or just uses milestone leveling :P Anyway, yes, I know what you mean, I’m just saying that I’m not sure that the law cares.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Anyway, I’ve [asked the question on the Law Stack](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/101586/3413), so we’ll see.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure, though, why it's important that the reader's could concoct solutions to this problem on his own. I mean, if you knowingly buy a car that's missing proprietary part, you can either manufacture your own part or buy the part from the dealer, but you don't have to do either if some dude is just *giving away* the part! But I will wait and see if answers address that. Again, thank you.

Comment: The [FAQ on D20srd.org](https://www.d20srd.org/faq.htm) includes this explanation to "Where it the experience points table?": `The d20 license restricts some information from being included. Specifically…
"No Covered Product may contain rules or instructions of any kind that:
Describe a process for Creating a Character
Describe a process for Applying the Effects of Experience to a Character"
`
However d20srd does also have the [Experience points table here](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/xp.htm).  Either FAQ are out of date, or able to avoid the restriction as "Not a covered product"

Comment: @RisingZan It’s worth noting that this provision is found in the d20 System License, and **not** the Open Game License. This is why, for example, Pathfinder could include its own XP table and rules for creating a character and applying experience to a character. (Also, please do not use code formatting for quotations or emphasis or any other non-code purpose; it can harm site accessibility.)